# Adjacent irregularly shaped images

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Is it possible to have irregularly shaped images positioned adjacent to each other, where each individual image is clickable within its own boundaries?

For example, if I had a map of the US and I want to click each state and have a separate segue for each:

[image]

(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Map_of_USA_with_state_names.svg/2000px-Map_of_USA_with_state_names.svg.png)

I appreciate any tips/pointers in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the map is really a bunch of irregularly shaped images, or just one image, is immaterial. (The latter will be easier.) You can just define a separate `UIBezierPath` objects that outline each of the states, and then you can use the `UIBezierPath` method `containsPoint` to determine whether some tap point is contained within the respective state.

Frankly, you might consider how much accuracy you really need. For example, if looking at map of US from continental scale, you really don't need extremely accurate bezier paths. Often a simple irregular polygon shape can approximate the boundaries and is more than sufficient for hit tests.

In fact, you sometimes deliberately use a much bigger bezier path. For example, you might draw a single path that goes around all of the Hawaiian islands, with some leeway, so that you don't have to tap right on the actual island, but just somewhere close. Or, for Rhode Island, you might allow a tap on the text "Rhode Island", as well as the state itself.

Comment: I will research UIBezierPath. Thanks for the starting point and your insight.